# How to create solve 'TypeError: connection.Db.collection is not a function' error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

1. Goal:
   ++Hello, I am trying to access a mongodb database with some node.js code but I have hit an error (`TypeError: connection.Db.collection is not a function`) when using a dB.collection function. I would like to know what function I can use to perform queries on a mongo database/collection. 
   The initial call is an axios get request which is hands off some parameters to be used to perform the database query.

++I expected my function to return a matching database entry

CODE

```
const DbConnection = require('./DbConnection');

//const connect = () => new DbConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/noteworx');
const connect = () => new DbConnection('mongodb+srv://usernm:PASSWD@cluster0-xxxxx.mongodb.net/testsample?retryWrites=true&w=majority');

class NoteRepository {


    getMeasure(currentIngredient, collection){
        const connection = connect();
        console.log('Enter Repo');
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            connection
                .open()     //DBconnection: Connected to MongoClient>>
                .then(() =>{
                    connection.Db.collection(collection)
                        .findOne({_id:currentIngredient})
                        .then(notes => {
                            console.log('We found it:' + notes._id);
                            resolve(notes);
                            connection.close();
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            reject(error+'NoteRepos: Opened connection but could not find the note');
                            connection.close();
                        });   
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    reject(error+'NoteRepos: Could not open connection');

                    connection.close();
                });

        });
    }

}

module.exports = NoteRepository;`
```

The error message I received in the server terminal is the following:

```
mongodb+srv://usernm:PASSWD@cluster0-xxxxx.mongodb.net/testsample?retryWrites=true&w=majority
(node:55020) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
DBconnection: Connected to MongoClient>>
TypeError: connection.Db.collection is not a functionNoteRepos: Could not open connectionNoteManager: Returned nothing from Database (Repos) Router: Returned nothing from the formatting
::1 - - [25/Apr/2020:02:43:06 +0000] "GET /api/notes?ingredient=honey&collection=wet HTTP/1.1" 500 - "http://localhost:9000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36"
```

I am sorry I left out some code for theDbCollection file:

```
'use strict';

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

class DbConnection {

    constructor(connectionUri) {
        this.Uri = connectionUri;
    }

    open() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(this.Uri);
            MongoClient.connect(this.Uri)
                .then(db => {
                    this.Db = db;
                    console.log('DBconnection: Connected to MongoClient>>');
                    resolve();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error+'DBConnection: Could not connect to MongoClient>>');
                    reject();
                });
        });
    }

    close() {
        if (this.Db) {
            this.Db.close().catch(error => console.log(error+'Connection drop'));
        }
    }
}

module.exports = DbConnection;
```

2. Using localhost option `const connect = () => new DbConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/noteworx');` works fine

I have tried the following:
I updated mongodb to 3.5.6. I read about updating mongodb here on StackOverflow. I also whitelisted my IP address in Mongo Atlas. In addition, I ensured I had a user in my mongo database. None of these methods cleared my error.

Thanks

Comment: It means the `Db` is `undefiend` or `null` maybe.

Comment: Strange because it worked fine for the localhost connection on the original code. I added the referenced file for more details if that helps. That file define 'dB'

Answer (score 0):

I changed code and now it works!:

```
'use strict';


const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;


const url = 'mongodb+srv://usernm:PASSWD@cluster0-xxxxx.mongodb.net/';
const dbName = 'testsample';


console.log('Beginning');
class NoteRepository {


    getMeasure(currentIngredient, collection){


        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            MongoClient.connect(url)       // connect to mongo server
            .then(client => {client.db(dbName)           
                .collection(collection)         
                .findOne({_id:currentIngredient})           
                .then(notes => {
                    resolve(notes);
                    client.close();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    reject(error);
                    client.close();
                });               
            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error+'NoteRepos: Could not open connection>>');

                client.close();
            });
        });
    }       

}


module.exports = NoteRepository;
```